# Two aggregate functions in MS Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT c.Category, SUM(c.[Market Value]), SUM([p.Market Value])
FROM Dec AS c, [NOV] as p
GROUP BY c.Category
;
```

Tells me the category is not part of the aggregate function. I just want to see the sums of each category for both tables. I do not want only certain values to appear so should I use Join?

EDIT:

```
SELECT c.[Category],  SUM(c.[Market Value]), SUM(p.[Market Value])
FROM Dec AS c
INNER JOIN Nov AS p ON c.ID = p.ID
GROUP BY c.category, p.Category
;
```

This is what I wrote using JOIN, it just runs the query for nonstop. Do I just wait? There are 80,000 rows of data, but doing one SUM grouped by category for just one month returns it instantly, why is it so hard to do two tables?

Comment: you should change you database design. Having a table per month is a bad idea. To answer your question: you need to use `UNION ALL`

Comment: I agree, but it is not my rules. Furthermore there are around 80K rows of data per month. Thanks for the answer, appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it. I do not want the sum of both months together :( I would like the sum of each month in two separate columns.

Comment: use union all, but in the Sum column use `SUM(iif(month='Dec', [Market Value], 0)) as Dec_Value, SUM(iif(month='Nov', [Market Value], 0)) as Nov_Value`. Comment back if you still have troubles

Comment: Well, the tables do not actually have a month or date column : /. It is simply the name of the table. There is also no column that will distinclty distinguish between the tables. You have given me the solution though, I just need to find a substitute for 'month=dec'. Although I am interested, what is the meaning of the 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to UNION ALL your data:

```
SELECT Category, [market Value]
FROM DEC
UNION ALL 
SELECT Category, [market Value]
FROM NOV
```

When you run this query you will get the combined data for two months. If you want to get the sum for the combined data the just use the query:

```
SELECT Category, SUM([market Value]) as sum_value
FROM (
SELECT Category, [market Value]
FROM DEC
UNION ALL 
SELECT Category, [market Value]
FROM NOV
) as A
GROUP BY Category
```

Now, this is not what you want. You want two columns: one for Nov, one for Dec. To do this you need to slightly modify the UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT Category, [market Value], 'Dec' as type
FROM DEC
UNION ALL 
SELECT Category, [market Value], 'Nov' as type
FROM NOV
```

And the final query will be:

```
SELECT Category, 
SUM(iif(type='Dec', [Market Value], 0)) as Dec_Value, 
SUM(iif(type='Nov', [Market Value], 0)) as Nov_Value
FROM (
SELECT Category, [market Value], 'Dec' as type
FROM DEC
UNION ALL 
SELECT Category, [market Value], 'Nov' as type
FROM NOV
) as A
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: Holy moly. That is disgustingly accurate. Thanks for the huge effort you obviously went through.

Comment: One question though, why do you put an 'AS A'?

Comment: This is called Column/Table <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp">alias</a>